# cap = new Capture(0); does not detect webcam?

Tags: c#, webcam, emgucv, face-detection

I use EmguCV in C# to for simple eye tect program.

but

```
cap = new Capture(0);
```

Always return null value.

It does not detect webcam. Why this happen and how to solve it ?emgucv

Comment: Have you tried to use the default camera? I mean, cap = new Capture();

Comment: Yes ... It also did not work

Comment: how many cameras you are connecting? do you have any inbuilt camera? try changing the values e.g. capture(1);